# Format from terminal(ctrl+alt+f1)

Tags: command-line, uefi, format

24 hours ago I start using for the first time Ubuntu 14.10. I tried to install AMD GPU drivers and then I install from the terminal the `fglrx` and after a restart I got the

```
The system is running in low-graphics mode
```

error. I tried to fix it but nothing.

I don't have any data to care if I lose it.

Can I format the laptop from the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and after install Ubuntu again? I can't change the Boot Priority from the UEFI/BIOS because I can't disable the Secure Boot for some reason.

I'm  new user and I don't know much about ubuntu so excuse me.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=Install+AMD+GPU

Comment: How did you install the system? With CD / DVD, USB Flash Drive?

Comment: when i had win8 i boot the usb from the win8 Troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start over from scratch:  Boot the LiveDVD/USB, erase everything and re-install.  That will "format" the laptop…

Low quality reviewers:  OP asks how to "format" his laptop…  Nothing more to say, really! **;)**

Comment: How can the system from CD / DVD will start if it can not change the boot order?

Comment: @A.B. By booting the CD from the UEFI menu instead of the BIOS menu...

Comment: FINALLY.... after hours the laptop just boot the ubuntu install from the usb...Btw im new on the linux think so im sorry if my questions is stupid....

Comment: There are no stupid questions.  Only stupid answers!  ;-)